# Are there any open-source check-in / check-out systems?

Tags: php, open-source, registration, barcode

I work for a building where people check in when they arrive, and are supposed to check out when they leave. It's necessary for:

- Fire regulations
- It tells the receptionist whether the visitor's membership is valid
- The marketing team want to use it for CRM

At present, the visitor checks in by scanning their membership card with a barcode reader, and speaks to the receptionist to check out. However, this process is really inefficient for both visitors and the receptionist, and so the data is usually quite inaccurate.

I'm looking for solutions that are a bit more robust. Obviously, I could build something, but I'm wondering if there is some kind of open source solution already out there. It would need to have an API to integrate with the other existing systems.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find **one** open source project: **[PHPTimeClock](https://github.com/SteveCastle/PHP-Time-Clock)**

After a short code review, I noticed that it does **not** have top notch coding practices. However it does offer a quick way to kickstart a similar project and at the very least gives some idea on where to start.

It also is not actively maintained (considering the last/only commit was 7 months ago).

Taken from [ohloh.net](http://www.ohloh.net/p/phptimeclock):

> Originally founded by Ken Papizan, PhpTimeClock grew to be an easy to use and stable time-clock solution for many companies. After a short while of inactivity the project was revived and given new life in the form of a new website and new code. PhpTimeClock strives to become the premiere open source time-clock solution, suitable for small companies and large enterprises.